# determinant blocks with $0$, identity, other two $A,B$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $M \in M_{nxn}(F) $ can be written in the form 
   $$M= \begin{pmatrix} A  & B \\ 0 & I \end{pmatrix} $$
 where $A$ is a square matrix. Prove that $\det(M)=\det(A)$

---

here is my scratchwork $$ |M|= \begin{vmatrix} A  & B \\ 0 & I \end{vmatrix} =AI-0B$$ 
which is of course a bunch of nonsense.

either ways using the cofactor expansion formula along the last row assuming it is nxn $$|M|=(1)^{n+n}\left|\widehat{M}_{n,n}\right| $$
which is somehow $|A|$. Guessing the good prove has induction but I am having trouble with even the basis step because when $n=1$ it is just one entree.  Do not see how it applies to our $M$.

Guessing another cool way which might be simpler is to use the somewhat linearity of determinant to show it is just $|A|$ which might honestly have a better chance

Comment: How about expanding by minors along the last row, until $I$ goes away?

Comment: @carlHeckman not sure what expanding by minors means guessing it is same as cofactor expansion formula?

Comment: Yes, it's also called that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have all the pieces; just put them together in the right way.

Theorem: $\det \pmatrix{A&B\cr 0&I_n\cr}=\det A$.

Proof: Induction on the size of $I$; if $I$ is absent ($n=0$), then you're done.

Otherwise assume that the result is true when $I$ is $k\times k$; it's also true when $I$ is $(k+1)\times (k+1)$. Expand by minors along the bottom row:

$$\det \pmatrix{A&B\cr 0&I_{k+1}\cr} = (-1)^{n+n} \cdot 1 \cdot \det \pmatrix{A&B'\cr 0&I_k \cr} = \det \pmatrix{A&B'\cr 0&I_k \cr} = \det A.$$

(Here, $B'$ is the matrix obtained from $B$ by deleting the last column of $B$.)

Thus, the result is true for any sized $I$. QED